# Should we return never when function throws error

Tags: typescript

Should we return `never` from function, whenever this function may throw an error? e.g.

```
function verifyIferror(): never | void {
  if (someCondition) {
    throw 'My Error';
  }
}
```

Or is it correct just to return `void`?

Additionally, would it be correct to return `never` in function which calls this function? e.g.

```
function myOuterFunction(): never | number {
  verifyIferror();
  ... some other code ...
  return someNumberValue;
}
```

And returns `never` until we at some point we catch this exception and handle it in some nice fashion?

Comment: If the error doesn't contain any details the caller can deal with, not returning anything (or returning `null` or something) makes sense, and doesn't require unwinding the call stack.

Comment: I need to learn what `unwinding the call stack` means now. Thank you for answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) is TypeScript's [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type).  That means it is completely uninhabited: you can have a value of type `string`, or type `RegExp`, but you cannot have a value of type `never`.  If you tell me you have a value of type `never` I know you are lying to me.

Logically speaking, this implies that for any type `A`, the union `A | never` is the same type as `A`.  After all, the values of type `A | never` is the union of all the values of type `A` with all the values of type `never`.  But there are no values of type `never` so that means the values of type `A | never` are the same as those of type `A`.  So `A | never` is identical to and can be simplified to just `A`.

The TypeScript compiler recognizes this, and performs this simplification for you:

```
type StringOrNever = string | never;
/* type StringOrNever = string */
```

which you can verify via IntelliSense.

That means that while it's not *wrong* to write a signature like this:

```
function foo(): string | never {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) throw new Error("sorry");
    return "hello";
}
```

it doesn't really buy you much.  Even someone using the function will see the return type as only `string`.  Notice that this also implies that you can use return values without worrying about `never`.  If the runtime throws an error before it gets to the code, then it won't run at all and you don't have to worry.  If it makes it to your code, then the `never` possibility is already eliminated (further justifying the idea that throwing an error is the same as returning a bottom type):

```
const s = foo(); // maybe error here
console.log(s.toUpperCase()); // if not, logs HELLO
```

See, the type of `s` is just `string`, and I can write `s.toUpperCase()` with impunity.

---

Okay, hope that helps you; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwPLwHIQG4XigF4oBnBFVKAHymTwIG4AoAegCopRJYK1Mc+QiXJI0Udq2bMAZgFdkAY2CIA9sigzVqgBQBKAFxk+VWvSFQA3syi2oiGVB0BZAIbAAFgDp4r5ABNVAFt9KAAeKAAGLwBWPS4PeFUAdzoIVIBReCT4HQAiUlVskDy9FjsoeAhgOXgNPI8IABsm1TyWAF9pRXVyMmJNbX1GKFZWKCDXEAAjaAIcqEaq5h7kQqaIL1bUHVIvYFUAVTBIeABhV1IIfTLR8Yc6VWAAGiht0igACQyAGR-0ZhAA)

Comment: The line `if (Math.random() < 0.5) throw new Error("sorry");` is hilarious to me, for some reason.